# Getting a WSGI error that i really don't understand

Tags: pythonanywhere

Whenever I reload my webpage i get this error in the errors page...

I'll share the error and then I'll share the wsgi file.

Error:

```
2020-10-10 16:39:25 Sat Oct 10 16:39:25 2020 - received message 0 from emperor
2020-10-10 16:39:25 SIGINT/SIGQUIT received...killing workers...
2020-10-10 16:39:26 worker 1 buried after 1 seconds
2020-10-10 16:39:26 worker 2 buried after 1 seconds
2020-10-10 16:39:26 goodbye to uWSGI.
2020-10-10 16:39:26 chdir(): No such file or directory [core/uwsgi.c line 1610]
2020-10-10 16:39:26 VACUUM: unix socket /var/sockets/www.oriental-ghana.com/socket removed.
2020-10-10 16:39:40 *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.17.1 (64bit) on [Sat Oct 10 16:39:38 2020] ***
2020-10-10 16:39:40 compiled with version: 5.4.0 20160609 on 07 May 2020 19:40:56
2020-10-10 16:39:40 os: Linux-5.4.0-1020-aws #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 05:52:40 UTC 2020
2020-10-10 16:39:40 nodename: blue-liveweb6
2020-10-10 16:39:40 machine: x86_64
2020-10-10 16:39:40 clock source: unix
2020-10-10 16:39:40 pcre jit disabled
2020-10-10 16:39:40 detected number of CPU cores: 2
2020-10-10 16:39:40 current working directory: (unreachable)/etc/uwsgi/vassals
2020-10-10 16:39:40 detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
2020-10-10 16:39:40 *** dumping internal routing table ***
2020-10-10 16:39:40 [rule: 0] subject: path_info regexp: \.svgz$ action: addheader:Content-Encoding:gzip
2020-10-10 16:39:40 *** end of the internal routing table ***
2020-10-10 16:39:40 chdir() to /home/AliRedaM/
2020-10-10 16:39:40 limiting number of processes to 600...
2020-10-10 16:39:40 your processes number limit is 600
2020-10-10 16:39:40 your memory page size is 4096 bytes
2020-10-10 16:39:40 detected max file descriptor number: 123456
2020-10-10 16:39:40 building mime-types dictionary from file /etc/mime.types...
2020-10-10 16:39:40 552 entry found
2020-10-10 16:39:40 lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
2020-10-10 16:39:40 thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
2020-10-10 16:39:40 uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /var/sockets/www.oriental-ghana.com/socket fd 3
2020-10-10 16:39:40 Python version: 3.8.0 (default, Nov 14 2019, 22:29:45)  [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
2020-10-10 16:39:40 Set PythonHome to /home/AliRedaM/.virtualenvs/Oriental
2020-10-10 16:39:40 *** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
2020-10-10 16:39:40 Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1980590
2020-10-10 16:39:40 your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
2020-10-10 16:39:40 your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
2020-10-10 16:39:40 setting request body buffering size to 65536 bytes
2020-10-10 16:39:40 mapped 501384 bytes (489 KB) for 2 cores
2020-10-10 16:39:40 *** Operational MODE: preforking ***
2020-10-10 16:39:40 initialized 54 metrics
2020-10-10 16:39:40 WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x1980590 pid: 1 (default app)
2020-10-10 16:39:40 *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
2020-10-10 16:39:40 gracefully (RE)spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 1)
2020-10-10 16:39:40 spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 3, cores: 1)
2020-10-10 16:39:40 spawned 2 offload threads for uWSGI worker 1
2020-10-10 16:39:40 spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 6, cores: 1)
2020-10-10 16:39:40 metrics collector thread started
2020-10-10 16:39:40 spawned 2 offload threads for uWSGI worker 2
```

my wsgi file:

```
         +++++++++++ DJANGO +++++++++++
    To use your own django app use code like this:
    import os
    import sys

     assuming your Django settings file is at '/home/myusername/mysite/mysite/settings.py'
    path = '/home/AliRedaM/res'
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.insert(0, path)

    os.chdir(path)
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'project.settings'

    import django
    django.setup()
     Uncomment the lines below depending on your Django version
     then, for Django >=1.5:
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
    application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: I don't see an error message there -- that's normal informational stuff while uWSGI is starting up.  What is the underlying problem that you are having?  Is there anything in the error log (not the server log that you shared)?

Comment: No am not facing any problems I just which to understand this server log message..